# Parsear objeto array en php

Tags: php, array, webservice, xml

Estoy consumiendo un `Webservice Soap` de tipo `asmx` desde `PHP`. Recibo los datos pero no me entrega el objeto `array` ordenado con los campos que devuelve el `XML` del `Webservice`, es como que muestra todos los datos a la vez. Esto es lo que me entrega:

> stdClass Object ( [getClientesResult] => stdClass Object ( [any] => 210819SECTOR 1ALVAREZSAEZROBERTO ALEJANDRO210950SECTOR 1BOBADILLASILVAGLORIA JIMENA210968))

Los campos deberían ser: `id, sector, apellido1, apellido2, nombre`.

¿Como puedo hacer para parsear u obtener de una manera mas ordenada estos datos?

Esto es lo que tengo en `PHP`:

```
$servicio = "http://192.168.1.100:8093/wsclientes.asmx?WSDL";
$cod = 11;
$params = array('cod_sec' => $cod);
$client = new SoapClient($servicio);
$arr = $client->getClientes($params);
$res = $arr->getClientesResult;
print_r($res);
```

Gracias.

Comment: Considero que es sumamente complicado extraer la información de dicho objeto porque no hay al menos un delimitador para poderle hacer un `explode` y "parsearlo", ¿no sería más fácil cambiar el `WebService` para que te entregue correctamente la información?

Comment: el webservice esta hecho en .net (c#) y retorna un objeto de tipo datatable, quieres decir que ahi se podria hacer de otra forma?

Comment: Me refiero a que lo que el `WebService` te entrega debería ser "compatible" con `PHP`, es decir, un `JSON` o ese mismo objeto de tipo `stdClass` pero mejor estructurado

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar en tu pregunta el resultado de hacer `print_r($arr)`?

Comment: Haz probado el `WS` con algún utilitario como `SoapUI` o la extensión de `chrome` `Boomerang` , para verificar que la estructura de la respuesta sea correcta ya que asi podremos determinar mejor si es mas de `WS` o de `PHP`.

Answer (score 1):

La cadena devuelta parece responder a un patrón concreto:

Primero hay una serie de 6 números después está la palabra "SECTOR" seguida de un número y para finalizar una cadena que represanta el nombre completo.

Partiendo de la base de que siempre se va a seguir este patrón y asumiendo que habrán otras soluciones más completas a este problema, propongo una aproximación a la solución deseada.

Para resolverlo, he hecho uso de las  expresiones regulares para separar los datos de la cadena en los patrones observados, así obtenemos estos datos:

```
id, sector, nombre completo
```

El nombre sesulta imposible dividirlo en nombre y apellidos siguiendo esta estrategia.

La estrategia es la siguiente:

1. Separamos la cadena en subcadenas usando como delimitador el id(consecución de 6 números)
2. Por cada subcadena: separamos usando el sector que está compuesto por la palabra "SECTOR" más un número.
3. montamos el array con los resultados.

El código sería más o menos así.

**CÓDIGO:**

```
 <?php
    //Partiendo del array devuelto por el Webservice
    $array['any'] = '210819SECTOR1ALVAREZSAEZROBERTOALEJANDRO210950SECTOR1BOBADILLASILVAGLORIAJIMENA210968';

    //Separamos la cadena por el id del usuario que responde al patrón de una consecución de 6 números
    preg_match_all("/[0-9]{6}[A-Z]+[0-9]{1}[A-Z]+/u", $array['any'], $array);

       /* ahora $array contiene esto:
       Array
         (
         [0] => Array
         (
           [0] => 210819SECTOR1ALVAREZSAEZROBERTOALEJANDRO
           [1] => 210950SECTOR1BOBADILLASILVAGLORIAJIMENA
         )
       )*/

    $datos = [];
    $persona = [];

    foreach ($array[0] as $datos) {

        //Separamos el id del cliente
        preg_match("/[0-9]{6}/u", $datos, $id);
        $persona['id'] = $id[0];
        //separamos el sector al que pertenece
        preg_match("/SECTOR[0-9]{1}/u", $datos, $sector);
        $persona['sector'] = $sector[0];
        //Separamos el nombre competo utilizando como delimitador el sector
        $nombre = preg_split("/SECTOR[0-9]{1}/u", $datos);
        $persona['nombre'] = $nombre[1];
        //Lo añadimos al array de personas
        $personas[] = $persona;
    }

    //Este array contiene un array por cada uno de los clientes devueltos
    print_r($personas);
```

**RESULTADO:**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 210819
        [sector] => SECTOR1
        [nombre] => ALVAREZSAEZROBERTOALEJANDRO
   )

    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 210950
        [sector] => SECTOR1 
        [nombre] => BOBADILLASILVAGLORIAJIMENA
  )

)
```

**Nota:**

No soy expeto en exprexiones regulares, supongo que se pueden mejorar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar creando tu cliente SOAP con la siguiente opción:

```
$client = new SoapClient($servicio, ['trace' => 1, 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS]);
```

Al final manda

```
var_dump($client);
var_dump($arr);
```

Eso debe decirte tu situación actual, si lo que te regresa el WS es un string entonces habría que ver la forma de partir ese string tal vez con `explode()`